# Voltaic armor parts do not increase my automatrons energy damage?

Tags: fallout-4

When I put on the parts, the energy damage number does not change. Bug?

Comment: Isn't it just because the energy damage refer to their ranged damage? Those parts give melee bonus.

Comment: @Amarth But it's written "increases energy damage". If you don't have melee energy damage, it won't have an effect then? If I remember correctly, even the shishkebab knife didn't change its value when I tried it on.